# How can I wrap a ZipFile into a file wrapper? (invalid file exception)

Tags: python, zip

I have a problem when trying to use a Python Filewrapper around a zipfile. The zip gets generated alright, when I use the wrapper around "temp" like below. However, when I actually download the zip, I see

```
~/Downloads $ file data.zip
data.zip: empty
```

Indeed, this zip cannot be opened by unzip (End-of-central-directory signature not found).
If I wrap the archive in the filewrapper instead of the tempfile, I get

```
invalid file: <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x103e4e940>
```

I am not so familiar with Filewrapper and the print functions in the code seem to indicate that everything works alright constructing the archive.

Can someone indicate what might be the problem here?

```
def send_zipfile(request):
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
dir = getGeneratedFilesDir()
files = [f for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir, f))]

for filename in files:

    print(isfile(get_file(filename)), filename, get_file(filename).__sizeof__())
    archive.write(get_file(filename), filename)


print(archive.namelist(), archive.__sizeof__())

wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
archive.close()
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.zip'
response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()
temp.seek(0)

return response
```